# Updating Columns with Default Value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an editable interactive grid based on a table. I want to updated MODIFIED_DTS with date on which change was made, and MODIFIED_BY_USR_ID to capture who made the change automatically, when a user makes any change in the table.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there absolutely is a way to implement this. By far the best way is to create a trigger on the table your interactive grid is based on.
The easiest way to generate this trigger is to use quicksql, available on [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/). It generates a trigger like this:

```
create or replace trigger <your_table_name>_BIU
    before insert or update 
    on <your_table_name>
    for each row
begin
    if inserting then
        :new.created := sysdate;
        :new.created_by := nvl(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
    end if;
    :new.updated := sysdate;
    :new.updated_by := nvl(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
end tp_item_biu;
/
```

Replace your_table_name and "created, created_by, updated, updated_by" with your column names, compile and you're good to go.

Comment: The "best way" depends on a number of variables. :) The larger and more complex the system is, the more likely that access will not only be through APEX but through a variety of different mid-tier technologies (.NET, Java, Node.js, etc.). In such cases, a PL/SQL API that does the audit logic (instead of a trigger) in addition to all other necessary logic makes more sense. That's the idea behind SmartDB: http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2018/05/the-smartdb-resource-center.html Some people believe one should always take the SmartDB approach, but I don't think it's always necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use a database table trigger for that. The advantage is that it works everywhere in your app where the table is modified and in addition it will also work if someone outside your app modifieds the table. The coalesce will first look if the insert/update was performed in an APEX context and user the app_user, if not the current database user is used.

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger_name
    before insert or update on my_table
    for each row
begin
    :new.modified_dts        := sysdate;
    :new.modified_by_user_id := coalesce(sys_context('APEX$SESSION', 'APP_USER'), user);
end;
/
```